# Problems with scraping webpage

Tags: r

I am scraping the following webpage using R for its data: http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201403310.shtml . One particular concept I am interested is the Start Time Weather (located at half of the page), but I have been unable to scrape that information.

Using selector gadget, I coded:

```
game <- read_html(x= "http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201403310.shtml")

weather <- game %>% 
html_node(".section_wrapper+ .section_wrapper div:nth-child(5)") %>%
html_text() 

weather

[1] NA
```

How can I modify my code to avoid the NA? This also happens in other game's pages.

I hope you can help me! I can't seem to find the right path.

Comment: use `base::readLines`? like `lines <- readLines("http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201403310.shtml"); lines[which(grepl("Start Time Weather", lines))]`

Comment: chinsoon12, I just tried it and it worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `readLines` to subset the Start Time Weather line before parsing for the data as follows:

```
#http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI201403220.shtml
lines <- readLines("http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BAL/BAL201403310.shtml")

library(rvest)
weather <- read_html(lines[which(grepl("Start Time Weather", lines))]) %>% 
    html_node("div") %>% 
    html_text()
gsub("Start Time Weather: ", "", weather)
```